# Dimmer wired to 2 lights and half wall outlet

Tags: receptacle, ceiling-fan, light, dimmer-switch

I am pretty comfortable with wiring in a DIY sense but this has me stumped.  We have two ceiling fans, each with a light set.  At one end of the room is a standard toggle for turning fan lights off/on.  At the other end is a dimmer switch that dims the fan lights.  On the adjacent wall is an outlet and the top receptacle is connected to the dimmer switch.  The bottom plug works normally.  I would like to disconnect the dimmer from the receptacle (I accidentally plugged a space heater in and about set the house on fire - yikes).  Why would the builder do it this way and how to I undo it but still have the dimmer for fan lights?

Comment: Are you the original owner?

Comment: Turn off the breaker. Open up the receptacle box. Pull the receptacle out **but do not disconnect any wires**. Take pictures showing all the wires going to any/all: screws, cables, "backstab connections", wire nuts, etc. Upload those pictures ("Edit" -> "mountain and sun icon") and then we can figure this out. Most likely it will be: Replace the receptacle but with a couple of wires in different places, but the details matter a lot and there are a couple of different possible configurations.

Comment: Yes-original owner. These were installed by the builder and it took a while to figure out what was happening.   I’ll post pics thanks!!

Comment: @JACK Even if dimmer and fan/light were installed by the builder (might be, might not, we don't know yet) it is quite possible that the dimmer/fan/light was an extra cost option that not everyone in the development selected, so baseline electrician did the 1/2 split receptacle thing "everywhere" and then someone else came in to add the extras and didn't bother to undo the split.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  I'm sure we've seen a lot of that in our days.  I've done the ceiling wiring for fans and lights with switches on the walls but also added the extra wire to outlets in case "they" wanted a switched outlet instead.

Comment: @JACK First home improvement ~ 30 years ago - got someone to add lights to the bedroom ceilings wired to the wall switches and make the receptacles always on.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box for the receptacle in question?

Comment: Why is there a simple toggle for the lights at one entry way and a dimmer for those same lights at the other entry way? That's equally bizarre!